# Codeigniter project - trying to view the index page (main page in application) using XAMPP

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, indexing, view, xampp

In XAMPP and my current setup I can simply type in **https://www.localhost:1234/testsite**, and it will automatically load the index.php page in the directory testsite, and display it on the screen.

With codeigniter, I understand the routing is more complex, and I don't know what to do, as a complete beginner, to view the main index page.

The index page that I want to be the home (i.e loaded on typing in https://www.localhost:1234/public_html) is located in **C:\xampp\htdocs\public_html\application\views\home\index.php**

Can someone please suggest what I need to do to get this working?

I have tried this: https://www.localhost:1234/public_html/application/views/home .but it doesn't work

The .htaccess file, and yes this is a fully fledged hosted site, is as below: What do I need to change here, or can I delete it for working on localhost?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# force ssl
RewriteCond     %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule     ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```

What do I need to type in the URL, or change in the .htaccess file, or somewhere else to simply load the index file as shown above?

I assume a change needs to be made to these two lines, but I'm not sure what?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

would the https:///www.%HTTP_HOST} be changed to localhost:1234?

Also, I'm aware of the format as described on the codeigniter website:

https://www.localhost:1234/public_html/home/index/index.php

doesn't work either,

where home is the controller (in application) and index is the function, see below:

```
class Home extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('homes');

    }

    public function index()
    {
        //$key = $config['encryption_key'];
        $this->load->view('template/header.php');
        $this->load->view('home/index.php');
        $this->load->view('template/footer.php');
    }
```

I also tried localhost:1234/index.php/home/index as suggested below, to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your .htaccess I'm assuming this is a fully developed site and not just a blank CodeIgniter install. As such most of your .htaccess rules reference a remote or live site.

I cannot speak for your current setup, but basically by default with no `.htaccess` CI works as follows.

If you have a controller in `application/controllers/` called `Test.php` and a sub function called `some_method` then the url is `localhost/index.php/test/some_method`

In default CodeIgniter installs the index is at `localhost/index.php` or `localhost/index.php/index`. The welcome controller you see in default installs actually references `controllers/welcome` yet although you can access it via `localhost/index.php/welcome` you can also access it via `localhost/index.php` and this is where routes/default controllers come in to play. Explaining routes in depth is a bit outside of the scope of stack, but you can find more information here: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html

Being new to CI I can say that the documentation is quite good and you should take your time to understand the architecture before going forward.

---

If you wish to remove `index.php` and just see `localhost/test/some_method` you need some .htaccess rules https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/urls.html#removing-the-index-php-file

Comment: Thanks Alex, I tried https://www.localhost:1234/index.php/home/index ...where home is the controller and the function is 'index', but that doesn't work either. Are you saying deleting everything in .htaccess may help? I've added an update to show the controller and what I've tried

Comment: that would be a good start, just replace your htaccess with the one in the link. then try it again. furthermore, is your codeigniter `index.php` in `htdocs` or `htdocs/public_html`?

Comment: then `localhost/public_html/index.php/home/index` should work

Comment: thanks. It doesn't work. I deleted everything in the .htcaccess, but noticed, whenever I put in the url, it redirects to https://www.localhost:1234/ <<<so somehow it is adding the https automatically. Don't know where to remove this